# Insert array into postgresql error

Tags: postgresql, phalcon

I using Phalcon Framework and PostgreSQL

I try to insert an array to database column type: `varchar[]`:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "6" [2]=> string(1) "9" [3]=> string(2) "12" }
```

But getting following error :

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Please help me to fix this please

Comment: Please share your code. It's impossible to help you without some more context.

Comment: Show us your query code

Comment: Not sure what that code is supposed to be, but in Postgres you need to specify the array like this: `array['1', '6', '9', '12']`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Phalcon\Mvc\Model;
use Phalcon\Validation;
use Phalcon\Validation\Validator\Uniqueness;

class Document extends Model
{

    public $id;
    public $relatedocument;

    public function getSource()
    {
        return "document";
    }
```

=====Form======

```
<?php
namespace App\Modules\Backend\Forms;

use Idoc\Models\Document;
use Phalcon\Forms\Form;
use Phalcon\Forms\Element\Select;

class DocumentForm extends Form
{
    public function initialize($entity = null, $options = null)
    {
        $data = Document::find();
        $this->add(new Select('relatedocument[]', $data, [
            'using' => [
                'id',
                'name'
            ],
            'useEmpty'  => true,
            'emptyText' => '....',
            'multiple' => 'multiple', 
            'class' => 'form-control search-select'
        ]));
     }
```

=====addAction======

```
public function addAction()
    {
        if ($this->request->isPost()) { 
            $doc = new Document();
            $doc->relatedocument = $this->request->getPost('relatedocument');
            if (!$doc->save()) {
            $this->flash->error($doc->getMessages());
            } else {
                $this->flash->success("Văn bản đã được tạo");
                Tag::resetInput();
            }    
        }
        $this->view->form = new DocumentForm(null);
    }
```

Comment: [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40421287/edit) instead of posting an answer. press the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40421287/edit) button below your question.

Comment: in your form you name your element `relatedocument[]` but in your controller you are requesting `relatedocument`